# Recyclerview Item objects set functions in main class

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am coding a To-Do list and Using the Groupie Adapter. I created a ViewHolder class "TaskItem". In that ViewHolder class I am setting the layout and on the bind function I am setting the text the Item should show. This Items has two buttons and for multiple reasons I want to reach them in the main class where the Items are added to the adapter. How ever I found a solution but its a really bad one: I used the function adapter.setOnItemClickListener where I did all the other functions like other on click Listners etc. Everything basically works like this but you have to click on the whole item first till the Buttons from the items are clickable.

I need an other function to solve this like adapter.bindViewHolder but I don't know which arguments to pass in this and where I get those from.

```
    val tasksAdapter = GroupAdapter<ViewHolder>()  
    val recyclerViewTasks = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerViewTasks)
    recyclerViewTasks.adapter = tasksAdapter

    tasksAdapter.setOnItemClickListener { item, view ->
        val taskTextView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.taskTextView)
        val editTaskButton = view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.buttonEditTask)
        val taskCheckBox = view.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.taskCheckBox)

        editTaskButton.setOnClickListener {
            val editLayout = findViewById<View>(R.id.LayoutEdit)
            editLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            val taskEditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextTask)
            val exitButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.buttonExitTask)
            val deleteButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.buttonDeleteTask)
            val confirmButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.buttonConfirmTask)

            taskEditText.setText(taskTextView.text)

            exitButton.setOnClickListener {
                editLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                taskEditText.setText(taskTextView.text)
            }

            deleteButton.setOnClickListener {
                deleteTaskFromTasks(taskTextView.text.toString())
                loadTasks()
                editLayout.visibility = View.GONE
            }

            confirmButton.setOnClickListener {
                deleteTaskFromTasks(taskTextView.text.toString())
                addTaskToTasks(taskEditText.text.toString())
                loadTasks()
                editLayout.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
        taskCheckBox.setOnClickListener{
            addTaskToFinishedTask(taskTextView.text.toString())
            deleteTaskFromTasks(taskTextView.text.toString())
            loadTasks()
        }
    }

    class TaskItem(val taskText: String): Item<ViewHolder>(){
        override fun bind(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val taskTextView = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.taskTextView)
            val taskCheckBox = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.taskCheckBox)
            taskTextView.text = taskText
            taskCheckBox.isChecked = false
        }
        override fun getLayout(): Int {
            return R.layout.task
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the code for GroupAdapter?

Comment: thats the Groupie Adapter I implementet it using: implementation 'com.xwray:groupie:2.1.0'